# d3 on(click action using class instead of ID

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a d3 viz I am making and I am stuck with the on click action.

I have two shapes (square, circle) that are created based on the value of a (1 or 0). Then I gave each svg an ID of the b-value (ranging from 1 to 4) and a class of the year (ranging from 2000 to 2014) To be clear, each svg will only have one b value and year associated with it.

Example data :

> A: 0 B: 3 Year: 2012
>
> A: 1 B: 3 Year: 2008
>
> A: 1 B: 2 Year: 2012
>
> A: 1 B: 4 Year: 2006

using the last line of data creates:

> svg-circle class = '2006' id = 'b4'

The circle is dictated by A = 1
The class is created by the year
The id is created from the B value

So that part is done. Great! Another thing that is great is I have been able to filter the IDs (dictated by b-value) by clicking on the legend. I did it by following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5d621a60e2d1d02086bf).

```
    .on("click", function(){
         var active   = b4.active ? false : true,
         newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
         d3.select("b4").style("opacity", newOpacity);
         b4.active = active;
    });
```

This is cool, however I would like to do the same thing with my classes (which is created from the year). I have gotten this far:

```
    .on("click", function(){  
    ...
    ...
    d3.select(function(d) {return "." + d;})
        .style("opacity", newOpac);
```

the function d is the unique values of years. In the previous example it sets active equal to an ID (b4.active), how would I do this with a class? Is it possible? Do I need to do something else?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess your objects have a B property or something, so I guess what you want to do is:`d3.select(function(d) {return "." + d.B;}).style("opacity", newOpac);` or whatever the name of the property on your objects

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but I don't think I did a very good job of explaining my problem. I tried to make it more clear if you have some time/desire to take a look again. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand better now. So I guess you want to change the opacity of all elements with the same year (class) as the selected one? To answer you overall question, yes, it works to select using classes. What I would do :`.on("click", function(d){   d3.select("." + d).style("opacity", newOpac); );`. Note that I used the d coming from the click function directly and not internally. Hope this helps.